# Install a node package without its tests, readme, etc

Tags: node.js, npm

Is it possible to install a package via npm and exclude its tests and other files not necessary for using it?

Many packages include a lot of unnecessary files, I've seen some of them even include JPEG images for some testing - I don't want to download that, I just want to use their APIs.

Answer (score 1):

`You can't`, because npm downloads all the files whether it's required or not. However it is possible to import part of the npm library in your app.

If you want you can delete unused part manually from node_modules folder. But I'll not recommend it.